# c++/sprintf: unrecognized character escape sequence

Tags: printf, warnings

How to avoid these sprintf warnings ?

```
C4129: '#' : unrecognized character escape sequence
C4129: ':' : unrecognized character escape sequence

sprintf(szBuf,"1312:%d\#%s\:",iVal,pUser)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a literal `\` in your strings, you should write it as `\\`.

The `\` character starts an escape sequence and neither `#` nor `:` are valid as the second character. It's meant to allow for things like newline `\n` or tab `\t`.

Of course, if you don't wish to have `\` in your resultant string, just remove it altogether.